# 405 Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, deep-learning

i have deep learning model saved it as h5 and wanna access it via local host by using flask so I built simple app.py and html to try but encountered this problem "405 Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL." This my graduation project later I will connect the model to android application with firebase.

**this is app.py code:**

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('HistoModel.h5')
    print(" * Model loaded")

def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
image = image.resize(target_size)
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

return image

print(" * Loading Karas model...")
get_model()

@app.route('/predict' , methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(512, 512))

    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()
    
    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'Cancer': prediction[0][0],
            'No Cancer': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**and this is the html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Cancer detection app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="image-selector" type="file">
    <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
    <p style="font-style: italic">Predictions</p>
    <p> Cancer:<span id="Cancer-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> NoCancer:<span id="NoCancer-prediction"></span></p>
    <img id="selected-image" src="" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let base64Image;
        $("#image-selector").change(function () {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                let dataURL = reader.result;
                $('#selected-image').attr("src", dataURL);
                base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
                console.log(base64Image);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($("#image-selector")[0].files[0]);
            $("Cancer-prediction").text("");
            $("NoCancer-prediction").text("");
        });

        $("#predict-button").click(function (event) {
            let message = {
                image: base64Image
            }
            console.log(message);
            $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", JSON.stringify(message), function (response) {
                $("#Cancer-prediction").text(response.prediction.Cancer.toFixed(6));
                $("#NoCancer-prediction").text(response.prediction['No Cancer'].toFixed(6));
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding 'GET' to methods but doesn't help.

Comment: Fix the formatting of your code.